# Проблема с Intent-filter в activity android 12

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intent-filter

Всем привет!
Есть приложение, в манифесте которого прописаны intent-filter,таким образом, что если в кастом таб приходит определенный url, то я открывается активити и в нём выполняются некоторые действия (а именно так у меня работает open authentication 2). И всё было прекрасно, пока мой samsung galaxy s20 не обновился до Android 12. И тогда нужное активити открываться перестало. В официальной документации нашел информацию только о необходимости добавить `android: exported = ""`. Добавил, ибо без этого приложение вообще не запускалось на свежей ОС, но вышеописанная проблема не ушла.
Коллеги, подскажите, куда капать, на что смотреть? Спасибо заранее всем.
Ниже мой manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.primer.primer">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


    <queries>
        <!-- Определенные приложения, с которыми вы взаимодействуете, например: -->
        <package android:name="com.android.chrome" />
        <!--
             Конкретные намерения, которые вы запрашиваете,
             например: для пользовательского интерфейса общего доступа
        -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent>
    </queries>


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:name="com.primer.primer.presentation.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.mlkit.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.primer.primer.presentation.ui.splash.SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.primer.primer.presentation.ui.auth0.MainAuth0Activity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.APP_BROWSER " />


                <data
                    android:host="develop.primer.ru"
                    android:pathPattern="/api_/my/login/.*"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: А зачем целых четыре разрешения на камеру? И что за ошибка в логах на Android 12?

Comment: Случайно продублировалось:)
В логах никаких ошибок нет.

Comment: Сейчас выяснил, что в браузере ссылка, хост которой указан в intent-filter не открывается на свежей ОС, на старой все норм выходит выбор через что открыть: браузер или моё приложение.

Comment: Код активити покажите

Comment: queries не обязательно совсем

Comment: Кажется, я понял, где проблема - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#android-app-links-verification-changes
android:autoVerify="true"

Comment: @АзатСагутдинов, т.е. вы добавили `android:autoVerify="true"` и всё починилось?

Comment: Кажется, вот тут, помимо помянутого вами атрибута, есть много полезного по дилинкам и 12 версии ОС: https://doordash.engineering/2022/01/25/your-deep-links-might-be-broken-web-intents-and-android-12/?utm_source=android_broadcast_te&utm_medium=post&utm_campaign=android12-your-deep-

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сегодня зальем файл assetlinks.json на сайт и проверим

Comment: файл добавили, не помогло..